# How to reply a tweet using the Twitter gem?

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
r = 569186681850601472

client.update('@ooidesigns work', in_reply_to_tweet_id: r)
```

I'm trying to reply a tweet using the twitter gem and the Client (`Twitter::REST`) class, but only the the message is tweeted and it does not reply the tweet.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please edit to shorten your question. Here the limit is 140 characters.

Comment: Better, but you need to remove 17 more characters in order to tweet your question to followers. [I hate to add the following, but I guess I must: :-)]. Go ahead and rollback your original question.

Comment: there is no character limit here, he's yanking your chain

Comment: @CarySwoveland not sure why did you touched character limit. '@ooidesigns work' is much less than 140 characters.

Comment: Efe, I hope you are the type who can laugh at oneself. If not, please accept my most sincere apologies. The allusion to Twitter's 140 character limit was a feeble attempt to put a smile on the reader's face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so [569186681850601472 tweet is this](https://twitter.com/Ksweeg/status/569186681850601472), right? It is made by `@Ksweeg` user and not by `@ooidesigns`. Therefore, in order to reply to this tweet, you should specify `@Ksweeg` in your tweet text:

```
r = 569186681850601472

client.update('@Ksweeg test tweet', in_reply_to_status_id: r)
```

Comment: hello, i just tried this and it creates a new tweet and doesn't reply the tweet by @ksweeg.

Comment: @EfeImoloame Just tried. [even though in docs written that they are the same](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet#in_reply_to_status_id-instance_method) -  `in_reply_to_tweet_id` doesn't work. So to summarize: use author of tweet in text and  `in_reply_to_status_id` instead

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to use `in_reply_to_status_id` e.g.

`client.update('@ooidesigns work', in_reply_to_status_id: 569186681850601472)`