# ruby twitter gem: tactical anti-troll response-bot replies, but timeline doesn't show tweet replied to

Tags: ruby, twitter, bots

I'm creating a bot to reply to certain words (designated likely 'troll' words) with quotes from the *George Orwell* novel *1984* using the 'twitter' ruby gem. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'twitter'
require 'thor'
require 'httparty'
require 'colorize'

puts '\|/|\|/'.red + ' Loading anti-troll tactical auto-canon! '.blue + '\|/|\|/'.red + "\n"

trollWords = ['Satan', 'Trump tower', 'libtard', 'nihilism', 'alt-right', 'feminazi', 'genocide', 'gulag', 'trigger-warning', 'special snowflake', 'privilege', 'ugly', 'moron', 'block-list', 'nazi']
quotes = ['Perhaps one did not want to be loved so much as to be understood.', 'Who controls the past controls the future. Who controls the present controls the past.', 'War is peace. Freedom is slavery. Ignorance is strength.', 'The best books... are those that tell you what you know already.', 'If you want to keep a secret, you must also hide it from yourself.', 'If you want a picture of the future, imagine a boot stamping on a human face — forever.', 'We shall meet in the place where there is no darkness.', 'But if thought corrupts language, language can also corrupt thought.', 'Doublethink means the power of holding two contradictory beliefs in one\'s mind simultaneously, and accepting both of them.', 'Until they became conscious they will never rebel, and until after they have rebelled they cannot become conscious.', 'The Party seeks power entirely for its own sake.', 'Russian Communists came very close to us in their methods, but they never had the courage to recognize their own motives.', 'Perhaps a lunatic was simply a minority of one.', 'If you loved someone, you loved him, and when you had nothing else to give, you still gave him love.', 'In the face of pain there are no heroes.', 'Big Brother is Watching You.', 'Reality exists in the human mind, and nowhere else.', 'Orthodoxy means not thinking--not needing to think. Orthodoxy is unconsciousness.', 'Nothing was your own except the few cubic centimetres inside your skull.', 'Confession is not betrayal.', 'Sanity is not statistical.']
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = '[key]'
  config.consumer_secret = '[secret]'
  config.access_token = '[token]'
  config.access_token_secret = '[token secret]'
end

word = trollWords.sample
quote = quotes.sample

def output_init_string(word, quote)
   puts "Troll identification word: " + word + ".\n" + "Response quote: " + quote
end

client.search(word, count: 10).each do |t|
  quote = quotes.sample
  word = trollWords.sample
  replystring = "@" + t.user.screen_name + " " + quote
  puts "Found possible troll suspect: " + t.user.screen_name + "\nTweeting: " + t.text + "\nReplied with: " + replystring + "\n"
  client.update(replystring, in_reply_to_status_id: t)
  sleep(300)
end
```

And it does work, but when I expand the details on a reply, I can't see the original tweet, only my bot's reply and @[user]. Can anyone tell me how to make it so the original user's tweet is visible on details expand?
So for example in the console output I can see:

[image: Trump towers reply]

But if I click on my bot's reply, I just see:

[image: Tweet without reply]

At https://twitter.com/bravebot1984/status/832328576619921413 with no indication of what the tweet was in reply to.

This question is not a duplicate of the linked to question, as I am already using the method suggested to 'reply', and the method does result in the reply of sorts, but it doesn't appear properly in details expand, as I need it to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reply a tweet using the Twitter gem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649582/how-to-reply-a-tweet-using-the-twitter-gem)

Comment: Not a duplicate as I am already using the method suggested in the answers to that question. This question is different because it asks not 'how to reply' but 'how to get the reply to correctly include replied to tweet on details expand'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that `t` is an instance of `Twitter::Tweet`. You could use `in_reply_to_status` instead of `in_reply_to_status_id` like:

```
client.update(replystring, in_reply_to_status: t)
```

See: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Tweets#update-instance_method

Comment: Still same issue. Seems it's happening intermittently whichever way. Been told it might be some issue with how Ruby handles 64 bit integers in JSON, but that seems odd since Twitter API was written in Ruby. Think I'm just going to give up and start automating with a Selenium instance instead of Twitter API as it doesn't seem to work properly half the time.

Answer (score 0):

in `in_reply_to_status_id: t` the `t` has to be the `id` of the tweet. Your current value looks like the object. Try `t.id` or `t["id"]`